# Running Docker with Postgres FATAL: cache lookup failed

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run Docker with a Postgres database. The part of my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Berlin
      POSTGRES_DB: my-db
      POSTGRES_USER: my-db-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: a23Kwum1Ql
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - main
```

When I run `docker-compose up` in the terminal, I get the error `FATAL:  cache lookup failed for access method 403`.

I tried to suppress the errors by running `docker-compose up -d` and then had a look at the database folders by running first `docker exec -i myproject-master_db_1 bash` and then `ls /etc/postgresql`. Result: The directory is empty which it shouldn't be to the best of my knowledge.

My database does not contain any important data, so I'd also be happy about solutions completely resetting the database (which I also tried but obviously failed).

Comment: If you want to reset your database you just need to delete the volume (docker volume rm VOLUME_NAME); when executing docker-compose again it recreates that volume

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks, you're a legend

Answer (score 0):

Your volume must be absolute, like ``/app/to/your/db-data`.

environment replace ':' by "="

Then make sure you got the right access on the volume/folder when running docker-compose

```
db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    privilied: true                 # Add this line
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin              # replace ':' to "="
      - POSTGRES_DB=my-db             # replace ':' to "="
      - POSTGRES_USER=my-db-user      # replace ':' to "="
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=a23Kwum1Ql  # replace ':' to "="
    volumes:
      - /app/to/your/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data # Update this line
    networks:
      - main
```